# using MERGE for insert too?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to ask that what are the disadvantages of using merge in replacement of insert statement? If I need to add and update data, why should I create 2 SP's for each of them? why shouldn't I just use one SP with `MERGE`?

Comment: as far as I know it's actually recommended to use merge in that scenario!
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317.aspx

Answer (score 1):

MERGE is fine as long as you don't forget to put TOP(1) clause "everywhere" if you're only merging 1 row per SP call.

```
MERGE TOP(1)
...
USING ...
    SELECT TOP(1)
...
```

Otherwise, there are scenarios you have to be pretty caution on how parameter sniffing could cause your MERGE to perform terribly.

Answer (score -1):

Merge will work fine when you have small amount of data but for large data it will cause performance issue. so its better to create two seperate SP's.